# Generic Traits dependent on each other in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have two generic traits that need to be passed to each other as type parameters. The code boils down to this

```
pub trait Entity<T: EntityRenderer<Self>>
    where Self: Sized
{
    fn get_renderer(&self) -> &T;
}

pub trait EntityRenderer<T: Entity<Self>>
    where Self: Sized
{
    fn get_animation_frame(&T) -> u32;
}
```

`Entity` needs to know what type it's `EntityRenderer` is, and vice versa. Later, I have

```
entities: Vec<Box<Entity>>
```

This is an issue, as I can't resolve the type parameter of `Entity`. I also can't make either of the functions which need the type parameter generic, because Rust's compiler won't let traits with generic methods become trait objects.

Is there any workaround? Or am I violating some sort of memory safety law that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with trait objects, because trait objects erase the real type of the underlying object. The giveaway is that, in order to use `Self` on the bound for `T`, you need the bound `Self: Sized`, yet that very bound disables the ability to use trait objects (like `Box<Entity>`). And we haven't even addressed the fact that `Box<Entity>` doesn't even specify a value for the type parameter `T` on `Entity`.

---

It looks like `Entity` (and maybe `EntityRenderer` too) should use [an associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html) instead of a type parameter. However, associated types won't solve your original problem; you'll get essentially the same problem, because you'd still need the `Self: Sized` bound and because you'd need to specify a value for the associated type on the trait object (`Box<Entity<Renderer=???>>`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this use of generics discouraged, then?

Comment: Generics and associated types both have their use. Associated types are best suited when the *implementation* decides the type. You'll usually make a generic trait when a single type could implement multiple instances of the generic trait (e.g. [`From<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html)).